# how to change excel cell format and locale

Tags: excel, vba

Platform: OS window 7

Excel: 2007

Issue : I had a .csv file with some data and date capture from other place. The data(date) is located in cell A2 having the category under Date. (e.g 18/3/2014)

Firstly there is this Locale (location), stated English (Singapore). I wanted to change it to English (United States)

After that then change the date format to "M/D/YYYY"

What i had tried:

```
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A2").NumberFormat = "M/D/YYYY"
```

it prompted me run time error "438"
object doesn't support this property or method.

how can make it that it return me the cell value as "3/18/2014"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in **A2** and see:

18/3/2014

then its either a String or a formatted date.  **it does not matter which** ;run this to fix it:

```
Sub FixDate()
    Dim s As String
    With Range("A2")
        s = .Text
        ary = Split(s, "/")
        .Value = DateSerial(ary(2), ary(1), ary(0))
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

If you want to **Dim** ary, then:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FixDate()
    Dim s As String, ary
    With Range("A2")
        s = .Text
        ary = Split(s, "/")
        .Value = DateSerial(ary(2), ary(1), ary(0))
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: your 5th line "ary = Split(s,"/") " the ary need to Dim as ...?

Comment: @Leon:  I rarely Dim the output of **Split**

Comment: after i only Dim ary, it encounter run time error on next line . value = Date...... (subscript out of range)

Comment: yup, i did the same, but encountered run time error '9':subscript out of range on next line .Value = DateSerial(ary(2), ary(1), ary(0))

Comment: **This is a valuable clue!**  It means that there are not "enough" ary's ............ it probably means that the cell does not have two "/" ............

Comment: Gary, i somehow the value was changed to "-" so i replace "/" with "-", so it's working.. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Well, a CSV file is just a Comma Separated Value File, so it doesn't support any of the cell formatting that an XLS or XLSX file would. So what you can do is:

If it only contains a date.

```
Dim dt As Date : dt = cdate(Range("A2").Value)
Range("A2").Value = Format(dt, "MM/d/yyyy")
```

If it contains a date and time and you only want the date.

```
Dim dt As Date : dt = cdate(Range("A2").Value)
Range("A2").Value = FormatDateTime(dt, 2)
```

if it contains a date and time and you want both.

```
Dim dt As Date : dt = cdate(Range("A2").Value)
Range("A2").Value = FormatDateTime(dt)
```

Comment: my cell format only consist of Date but is in "DD/M/YYYY" (e.g 18/3/2014) but i want the out put to be "M/D/YYYY"(3/18/2014) format, the method u mention changed the 18 to month =P